# Rails jquery ajax call not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, braintree-rails

I need to get a braintree token using ajax but its not firing. Normally I would generate the token in the new action but my orders form is a partial in a listing show page and thus I only have a create action. The token is needed for the braintree dropin to work. so I figured my only other option is to attach an ajax call to the checkout button but it wont fire. Would appreciate help on why the ajax is not working or even a better method of getting the token

routes.rb

```
 get '/token' => 'orders#token'
```

Then in my controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController      

def token
    @token = Braintree::ClientToken::generate() 
    render json: @token
end
```

in my html

```
<a class="btn btn-large waves-effect cyan waves-light modal-trigger" style="width: 300px;  margin-left: -65px;" id="btn-book" href="#modal1">Proceed to Checkout</a>


<script>
      $('#btn_book').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/token',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log('there was an error');
            }
        });

      });                        

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The id of your button is `btn-book` so you should be using `$("#btn-book")`, not `$("#btn_book")`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I've gone through it a hundred times but kept missing it. I am now successfully getting an error message, lol. If I could just figure out why the token isn't being sent over in the ajax call.